# handlebars correct path for lookup in each

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm trying to do a lookup in an each block, but it's not rendering anything, which leads me to believe it's undefined. I'm wondering if I have the path wrong.

Does the path start from the top level of the each, or the bottom?

```
{{#each totals.mapped_total.roo}}
    <div class="data_box>
        <span>Month {{ @index }}</span>
        <span class="mapped_vals">{{ this }}</span>
        <span class="unmapped_vals" style="display:none">
            {{#with (lookup ../../unmapped_total.roo @index)}}
                {{value}}
            {{/with}}
        </span>
    </div>
{{/each }}
```

Here's what the data looks like:

```
totals = {
u'unmapped': 0,
u'unmapped_total': {u'mdown': 0, u'rec_retail': 0, u'roo': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], u'inv': 0, u'sales': 0, u'rec_cost': 0, u'inv_fom': 0, u'tfrin': 0, u'mup': 0, u'tfrout': 0, u'venret': 0, u'coo': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]},
u'mapped_total': {u'mdown': 13, u'rec_retail': 29, u'roo': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], u'inv': 115, u'sales': 16, u'rec_cost': 12, u'inv_fom': 0, u'tfrin': 0, u'mup': 0, u'tfrout': 0, u'venret': 308, u'coo': [33, 17, 2, 1, 3, 11, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0]},
u'mapped': 15}
```

One final challenge, no helpers. Must do this out of the box.

The end goal is to toggle between mapped and unmapped.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I used that works:

```
{{#each totals.mapped_total.roo}}
<div class="data_box">
    <span class="month_label">>Month {{ @index }}</span>
    <span class="mapped_vals">{{ this }}</span>
    <span class="unmapped_vals" style="display:none">
        {{lookup ../totals.unmapped_total.roo @index}}
    </span>
</div>
{{/each }}
```